# Null collections converted to empty

Tags: java, immutables-library

By default, immutables.io will create empty collections if none are supplied.

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class MyTestPojo {
    public abstract List<String> myList();
}
```

The following will create the object with an empty collection:

```
MyTestPojo pojo = ImmutableMyTestPojo.builder()
        .build();
```

However, if the value is explicitly set to null, immutables will throw NPE.

```
MyTestPojo pojo2 = ImmutableMyTestPojo.builder()
        .myList(null)
        .build();
```

This could be avoided by allowing nulls with `@Nullable`. This would result in the collection being null. I would like this case to gracefully handle null and convert it to an empty collection.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not actually providing `null` as a parameter to `myList`, but rather a variable that happens to be null. If this is indeed the case, is anything preventing you from initializing that variable to be an empty list`

Comment: That is correct! I am not actually passing null, but rather a variable. The approach you mentioned is what I a currently doing (which is working fine). Only issue I have is I have to repeat the null check and create empty collection in quite a few places, and it is possible that someone can forget to do this in the future. I'd like to avoid this mistake ever being made in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into the [normalization feature](http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#normalization), which makes it possible to perform some modifications before the final instance is returned:

```java
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class MyTestPojo {
    @Nullable
    public abstract List<String> myList();

    @Value.Check
    protected MyTestPojo check() {
        if ( myList() == null ) {
            return ImmutableMyTestPojo.copyOf(this).withMyList();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Note that the `myList` property is annotated with `@Nullable`. The check will override the null value with an empty list during instantiation.

Comment: Thank you, I tested this solution and it does work as expected.